# How to mass delete facebook messages?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Trying to figure out a way to mass delete facebook messages any help appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Post this on GitHub/Gist (or whatever preferred service) or write a Medium/Dev.to article. This isn't a question for help or something that can help future coders, this is a tool that you want people to be able to use.

Comment: When someone asks the question it will come up here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't even a question, it's just the distribution of a small software

Comment: @Samathingamajig yay its a question now. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After September 17th, 2023, all previous codes no longer work

I updated it

This is the code that deletes all messages from Messenger

```js
function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
}
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

function doIt(){
console.log("1");
    getElementsByText = function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
    }
getElementByXpath = function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

    document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Menu"]')[1].click();

    setTimeout(function(){
      getElementByXpath('//span[text()="Delete Chat" or text()="Delete chat"]').click();
    },1500);

    setTimeout(function(){
      getElementByXpath('//div[(@aria-label="Delete Chat" and @tabindex="0")or(@aria-label="Delete chat" and @tabindex="0")]').click();
    },1000);

}

var myInt = setInterval(function(){ doIt() }, 2000);
```

Comment: Amazing, works well!!

Answer (score 1):

Here the updated function:

```
function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
}

function doIt() {

    getElementsByText = function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
    }

    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Menu"]')[0];
    buttons.addEventListener('click', event);
    buttons.click();

    setTimeout(function() {
        getElementsByText('Delete chat', 'div')[0].click();
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        this.getElementsByText('Delete chat', 'span')[2].click();
    }, 1000);

}

var myInt = setInterval(function() {
    doIt()
}, 500));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me on August 19th, 2023.

```
function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
}

function doIt(){

    getElementsByText = function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Menu"]')[0].click();

    setTimeout(function(){
      getElementsByText('Delete Chat', 'div')[0].click();
    },500);

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.getElementsByText('Delete Chat', 'span')[2].click();
    },1000);

}

var myInt = setInterval(function(){ doIt() }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is no clean way that I have found to do this, so I wrote something that works...
***USE AT YOUR OWN RISK!!!***

I needed to mass delete old messages and this does the trick.

Go to messenger.com and login.

hit f12 to open dev tools.

Paste the following in your browser:

```
function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
}

function doIt(){

    getElementsByText = function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Menu"]')[0].click();

    setTimeout(function(){
      getElementsByText('Delete chat', 'div')[0].click();
    },500);

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.getElementsByText('Delete chat', 'span')[2].click();
    },1000);

}
```

Then paste this...

```
var myInt = setInterval(function(){ doIt() }, 500));
```

This will start running an interval and deleting messages, you can watch it in action!

If you want to stop, refresh the page or

```
clearInterval(doIt);
```

Comment: Where exactly do we need to paste it on Firefox "Web Developer Tools"?

Comment: yes. Bear in mind that this post is over a year old so I haven't tested it recently.
Everything goes in the dev tools console.

Answer (score 0):

01 : open messenger in your tab

02 : click f12 or three dots in upper right > more tools > developer tools

03 : after that you must be in console and paste this code:

```
function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
}

function doIt(){

    getElementsByText = function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Menu"]')[0].click();

    setTimeout(function(){
      getElementsByText('Delete chat', 'div')[0].click();
    },500);

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.getElementsByText('Delete chat', 'span')[2].click();
    },1000);

}

var myInt = setInterval(function(){ doIt() }, 500);
```

note: this is totally working as of now in 2023, i just right the minimal wrong in the code. totally credits for the owner and thanks it helps me, just use it for your own discretion.

Comment: update: it's not working anymore for me, i think facebook noticed it. but try to run it for you.

Comment: Let’s keep this going because it’s helping some people. I don’t mind the downvotes. I needed a way to do this and nothing out there was working so I created a way.

Comment: hello, can you update the new code for the new fetches of facebook thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Facebook in Portuguese

01 : open messenger in your tab

02 : click f12 or three dots in upper right > more tools > developer tools

03 : after that you must be in console and paste this code:

```js
function getElementsByText(str, tag = 'a') {
  return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)).filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === str.trim());
}

function doIt() {
  // Removendo a reatribuição da função getElementsByText
  document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Bate-papos"] [aria-label="Menu"]')[0].click();

  setTimeout(function() {
    getElementsByText('Excluir bate-papo', 'div')[0].click();
  }, 500);

  setTimeout(function() {
    // Corrigindo a chamada para getElementsByText
    document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Excluir bate-papo"]')[2].click();
  }, 1000);
}

var myInt = setInterval(function(){ doIt() }, 2000));
```